# prove: the sum of segments connecting a point inside a triangle with its vertices is smaller than the semiperimeter of the triangle

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles

The question is from "Kiselev's Geometry: Planimetry". You can find the question here: http://schoolnova.org/classes/f2010/math7/assignments/Kiselev-pg-$41-48$.pdf. Page $41$, problem $94$ of the book. I just copied the question word for word.

Tried to do the problem first with an equilateral triangle of side with 1 unit and the centroid as a point. But the example disproves the statement. Semiperimeter $(1+1+1)\times0.5=1.5$ , and the sum of segments $(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\times3\times{\frac{2}{3}})=1.73.$ Therefore sum of segments is GREATER than semiperimeter.

Am I wrong with my example or is the book wrong on this problem?

Comment: There's a simple proof in the case "smaller" is replaced with "bigger". Consider the three small triangles made by the segments and the sides of the original triangle; add together the three triangle inequalities of each small triangle that compares the sum of inside segments with the length of the original triangle side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the book appears to be incorrect!

Here's a proof of the inequality in the opposite direction, for any triangle and any point (whether in the triangle or not).

Let $A$, $B$, $C$, be the vertices of the triangle, with corresponding perimeter segments $AB, BC, AC$.  Let $\bar{A}, \bar{B}, \bar{C}$ be the segments connecting the vertices to any point in the plane (doesn't need to be inside the triangle!).  The triangle inequality gives that $\bar{A} + \bar{B} \leq AB$, $\bar{B} + \bar{C} \leq BC$, $\bar{A} + \bar{C} \leq AC$.  Summing these inequalities, and noting that strict inequality must apply to at least one of them if the triangle has nontrivial angles, you've proved precisely that the sum of the segments connecting the point to the vertices is greater than the semiperimeter.

Now, see if you can prove that the sum of those segments is **less than** the perimeter.  This is also a true statement!

Comment: Yes, you are right that I am wrong on my first calculation on the sum of segments. I tried to reedit that part (maybe you have read the unedited version). I will try to prove "the sum of those segments is less than the perimeter" as an alternative exercise. thanks. Btw, some website actually have the theorem listed which further confused me: https://quizlet.com/110245809/theorems-flash-cards/ .

Comment: Yes, you're right.  That's disturbing.  
Edited answer to take your revision into account.  
The proof that the segments sum to less than the perimeter is similar to the proofs of all the facts in the link you provided.  Keep hammering away with the triangle inequality :)